# How to Calculate the Probability of Multiple Events Occurring on the Same Day?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a dataset containing 653 events over a period of 1095 days.

I want to calculate the probability that multiple events (more than one) occur on the same day. How can I do this?

My current thinking is this: the probability that at least one event occurs is 653/1095 = 0.596, and the probability that no events occur is 1 - 0.596 = 0.404. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

EDIT: sorry, I already know the *actual* probability of multiple events occurring on the same day. I want to calculate the theoretical probability assuming the distribution is random.

EDIT: I want to calculate the probability that multiple events occur on a *given day*, not all days.

FINAL EDIT: The reason I am doing this is because I want to compare the actual number of days with multiple events (163) to the *expected* number of days with multiple events. I want to determine if the observed pattern could be due to random chance.

Comment: What do you mean?  You have all the data...just look at the number of days on which multiple events happened and divide by the number of days.

Comment: You have the data, just count how many days have multiple events and divide by the total number of days.

Comment: Post edit:  this is the well known [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: To be clear... it sounds as though you are considering "*the first event occurs on any of the 1095 days uniformly at random*" and then "*the second event occurs on any of the 1095 days uniformly at random and independent of the first*" and so on... asking what the probability is that no day had more than one event.  Well....... this is just the birthday problem but instead of $365$ days for the birthday problem this is $1095$ days here and instead of $n$ students or $20$ students or whatever, this is $653$ events here.  The approach and solution is identical.

Comment: The probability of no day with more than one event is $\dfrac{1095\frac{653}{~}}{1095^{653}}\approx 5\cdot 10^{-110}$ where $n\frac{k}{~}$ is notation for the falling factorial $n\frac{k}{~}=\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}=\underbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}_{k~\text{terms}}$

Comment: But is that really what you want to ask?  Given the numbers, I'd say the chance of no days with more than one event is $0$.  Maybe you want to compute the expected number of such days? Something like that?

Comment: With regards to your attempted calculations... $653/1095$ is the expected number of events that occurred on very specifically the first day which is not particularly relevant to what it sounds like you are asking for.  The probability of at least one event occurring on the first day would be $1-\left(\frac{1094}{1095}\right)^{653}\approx 0.449323$.  The probability of strictly more than one event occurring on very specifically the first day would be $1-\left(\frac{1094}{1095}\right)^{653}-653\times\frac{1}{1095}\times \left(\frac{1094}{1095}\right)^{652}\approx 0.12064$

Comment: Re "Final Edit": "*What is the expected number of days with multiple events*"  Take the probability that a specific day has multiple events, in this case $\approx 0.12064$, and multiply by the number of days.  This gives $0.12064\times 1095\approx 132.1$.  You are slightly over the average with the stated value of $163$... but not hugely so.  There could be several other things at play here though, such as less (or more) events occurring on weekends, or less (or more) over holiday seasons, or friendships, which would throw off the uniformity and independence assumptions at the beginning.

Comment: It's a bit tedious, but not that hard, to compute the variance of the number of days with more than one event, that might help.  But, why not just sample it?  A good sampling engine is a vital tool in analyzing data.  Perhaps sampled data will reveal patterns you missed in the actual data.  Clustering, for instance.